# I can't solve the dependency tree every time i try to install @craco/craco

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Unable to solve dependency tree trying to install tailwind.

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.8",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "jest": "^28.1.0",
    "postcss": "^7.0.39",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "js-cookie": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "router": "^1.3.6",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .js,.jsx ."
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is what I see in my console:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: front-end@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react-scripts@5.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!   react-scripts@"5.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-scripts@"^4.0.0" from @craco/craco@6.4.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@craco/craco
npm ERR!   @craco/craco@"^6.4.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tejas\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-14T14_36_01_226Z-debug-0.log
```

i am trying to configure tailwind css and to override reactcss i am trying install @craco/craco but i am getting this error i tried useing

```
npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

and installed craco using this

```
npm install @craco/craco --save --legacy-peer-deps
```

but after that it is giving me error

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade the version of react-script from 5.0.0 to 4.0.0

Comment: This should be added as comment, not a separate answer. you will be able to add comment after gaining some reputations.